# Code in Javascript, using if, else and prompt.

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

I am trying to write a code to answer the following. I have options of prizes. To be eligible for the prizes, you need to be within the age range of 20 and 40. If you are not eligible an alert saying you are not eligible will appear. If you are eligible; prompt will ask you for which prize you want and you need to answer with a numeric value. After they answer they will receive an alert that says "You will receive (prize, collected from the array) in your post within 2 weeks."

I have gotten this far with my code:

```
var prize = [
    "0 = iPhone",
    "1 = iPad",
    "2 = iMac",
    "3 = iPod"
];
var age = prompt("Please enter your age");
if (20 >= age && age <= 40){
    alert("Sorry, you are not eligible for a prize.");
} else {
    prompt("Which prize would you like to receive?");
} else if {
```

Would someone want to give me a hand? Thanks :)

Comment: If the question text is not what you meant to type, please edit it

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. Do you have the answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The >= 40 bit it superfluous, it's already true if >= 20. Make it <= 40 to be consistent with an age range of 20-40, and also make it an && instead of a ||.

Comment: if (20<= age && age <= 40)

Comment: Thanks @HomerPlata. I changed the code, cause I originally meant to use <=40. However, nothing comes out.

Comment: You will need `age >= 20 || age <= 40` (or rather `age >= 20 && age <= 40`) as the condition to not get a syntax error. Notice the second `age`.

Comment: I did work before, but I have done some editing. Would greatly appreciate some help :)

Comment: May I ask why people is downvoting? I don't understand why. Would appreciate an explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: Now you've mixed up the statement to say 20 >= age instead of age >= 20

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up a lot of the logic there, and actually put the "success" code within the "failure" condition.

I have no idea what you intend to do with the second prompt to choose the prize - and have even less clue why someone's age is the limiting factor in being eligible for a prize - but here is some logic that will correctly filter your desired age range:

```
var age = prompt("Please enter your age");
if (age >= 20 && age <= 40){
    // handle successful prize claim here
}
else {
    alert("Sorry, you are not eligible for a prize.");
}
```